# Soldering a GPS antenna to a Samsung Tab 2

Tags: antenna, gps

I want to solder a GPS antenna to a Samsung Tab 2 tablet. 
I need it to increase its signal and because I have a bunch of them laying around. My question is, what should I connect where, and if I should use other electronic parts.

Samsung Tab 2 GPS antenna internal

http://www.fonejoy.com/media/catalog/product/cache/3/image/41a4ec2d52c38ed81ff0a55ea740edd5/f/i/filename5055866658617.jpg

Antenna that I have (similar):

http://image.dhgate.com/albu_253997659_00/1.0x0.jpg

The internal antenna have only one electrical isolated part, but the antenna have two.

I imagine that the internal antenna has no ground, but the external one has.

It would work if I only connect external non ground to internal electrical part?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the antenna you intend to add is similar to the one you show, it probably won't work directly in place of the internal antenna.  Your proposed antenna is an "active antenna", which means that it includes a preamplifier, which would be powered through the coax cable.

Comment: Further, the device is very carefully engineered for the antenna in the phone case to behave correctly. It's not a simple RF connector that's happily 50 ohms, but instead has specific components on the board to operate the antenna.